# MikroORM: How to use 'insert_id' for subsequent persists?

Tags: nestjs, mikro-orm

How can I get the insert_id (or existing id on duplicate key error) from a persist? I'd like to use it in following persists before flush.

In my mind, even though the EntityManager doesn't have an id yet, it could still populate that and use it during flush, but I think my thinking is flawed here, I'm new to MikroORM. From what I can see in the docs, I can only achieve this using the Query Builder.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just build the entity graph, the entity does not need to have a PK to be used in a relation:

```
const book = new Book(); // new entity, no PK
user.favorites.push(book); // doesnt matter if it has PK
await em.flush(); // if `user` was a managed entity, this will find the new book and save it to the database

console.log(book.id); // now we have the PK available on entity
```

In other words, the entity instance is what holds the identity, you use that, not the PK.

Comment: Hi, thanks! So I focused on persist because my question is more related on how to do this in a transaction. I want to be able to rollback the insert should there be a failure later. Can I wrap the flush in em.begin(), em.commit(), em.rollback() for example?

Comment: It seems that I can't get an insert_id placeholder, I have to get the id by flush(), which itself is a commit/rollback and can't be wrapped in a try/catch with em.begin() and em.rollback(). It seems that the only way would be to use Query Builder, can this be wrapped in em.begin(), em.rollback(), is that possible?

Comment: You can wrap the code in `em.transactional` or use `em.begin/commit/rollback` explicitly.

Comment: I dont follow the second comment, again, you dont need any placeholder, you work with entity graph, not with PK values.

Comment: Did some reading on this, got it!! thanks for your guidance